# exit application on double tap with message (Please click BACK again to exit ) ......unity

Tags: unity, android

Can anyone please help me here? This is not quite related to programming.

I want to exit my Android application on back button tap with conformation for exit

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
        super.onBackPressed();
    else 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in c#

```
void Update(){ 
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))  
    Application.Quit(); 
 }
```

or in .js

```
function Update(){ 
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))  
    Application.Quit(); 
 }
```

This is the function for exit app when back button pressed, if you want to exit the app when back button pressed twice, implement the logic in the java code you have posted in question into equivalent code in unity i.e initialise a variable to store current time in millis on first back button press and show message to press once again to exit, and if next back button press is within two seconds of first press, then exit app.

If you want this to work on a button click etc, implement the same technique and call `Application.Quit()` instead of `super.onBackPressed()` in java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you alok nair for your answer......but am not a good programmer and i already had tried the c# code which you posted and its working ....but now i want to pop up a message like (Please press back again to exit) like that and close app..... please help me with the code

Comment: You can learn how to create a toast in unity here:
http://nevzatarman.com/2014/04/03/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-series-part2-lets-make-a-toast/
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/creating-an-android-java-plugin-for-unity3d/

Comment: Implement a toast plugin as in links in above comment and if any doubts there, post a question for help in those or update present question.

Comment: Really really much much much than you for your kind help........with the help of blog which you gave with that i found the way to make with eclipse.......and i tried with AVD......and its WORKING......Thank You opnce again......cheers dude.....

Comment: Yw buddy. If you found the answer helpful, mark it as correct by clicking the tick mark near my answer. Have also answered your question on stackoverflow, you may also click tick there, will be useful for someone else referring this question in future.

Comment: Now problem is how can i call jar plugin which i created in java programme to unity.....

Comment: alok nair .........i have created a plugin to make a toast message when i press back button.......i do not know how i need to make it work with unity pls help